# Avoiding Numerous Declarations

Tags: java, enums

I'm writing a class that is dependent on months and how many days each month has. At the beginning of my class, I've written:

```
static final int    JAN = 1;
static final int    FEB = 2;
...
static final int    DEC = 12;
```

It looks like a messy way of doing this, and I feel that enums would be more efficient. I need to be able to "increment" the month (where DEC + 1 = JAN), and need to be able to know have many days there are in the month (with FEB having 28).

I see two ways of doing this:

1. My current way, defining static final ints and using a switch statement to find the number of days, and when incrementing I always checks for whether the value would be greater than 12.
2. Create a set of enums, each with inputs for which month of the year it is and how many days it contains, and defining an "increment" method.

Is there a better way of doing this, or is (presumably) 2. the best way of doing this?

Comment: Don't. Simply don't do that. Please. Use the built-in classes for date-time handling. Unless you like to hurt yourself.

Comment: Look at the new Java Time API. Don't read the answers pointing to the old Calendar class...

Comment: Are there any particularly advantages/disadvantages to one or the other, or in what way do they differ in how they function?

Comment: Calendar is clumsy to work with and is replaced by Java Time beginning with Java 8, which is _a lot_ easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using java.util.Calendar for this sort of situation.  It already has constants defined for virtually every date- and time-related concept that you'll ever have to use; plus, it is smart enough to know about things like February's wishy-washy length (29 days 25% of the time).

Answer (score 0):

Java has a Class that does what you need. See the `Calendar` class, which also has constants for Month and Day of Week:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html